# Extracting values within bracket in R

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I have a df with column named '**error (range)**' containing the values with error range like below,

| error (range) |
| --- |
| 25 (20 - 30) |
| 42 (39 - 48) |
| 35 (32 - 38) |

But I want to extract the values and my df columns should look like,

| error | error_min | error_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 20 | 30 |
| 42 | 39 | 48 |
| 35 | 32 | 38 |

Can anyone help me with the coding in R to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   set_names('error')%>%
   separate(error, c('error', 'error_min', 'error_max'), 
                convert = TRUE, extra = 'drop')

  error error_min error_max
1    25        20        30
2    42        39        48
3    35        32        38
```

Comment: Can you please kindly explain the code? df is my data frame name, what is 'error' in set_names()? When i tried It gave me following error - no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: what about the error - no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "character"?

Comment: Actually that is a column of a dataframe, I am sorry for my wrong description. I will edit the question.

Comment: @learner are you unable to get the logic from the code I provided? Have you used tidyverse before? iSince its a column in a dataframe, just do`df %>% separate(your_column_name, ....)`

Comment: As you said, I tried with seperate() only, and It worked for me. Thank you so much for your patience and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, read with `read.table` after removing the brackets and `-` with `gsub`

```
read.table(text=gsub("\\(|\\)|-", "", df[["error (range)"]]), 
  header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, fill = TRUE, 
  col.names = c("error", "error_min", "error_max"))
  error error_min error_max
1    25        20        30
2    42        39        48
3    35        32        38
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(`error (range)` = c("25 (20 - 30)", "42 (39 - 48)", 
"35 (32 - 38)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```